# Array element access with lens in the state monad

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

What is the recommended way to access an element of an array within the state
monad with [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) if the value type
is not a monoid.

The following will fail to compile, because lens doesn't know what to do if
there is no element at the given index `i`.

```
type MyArray = Array Int Char
-- accessElemInStateWrong :: Int -> State MyArray Char
-- accessElemInStateWrong i = use $ ix i
```

A working version can be implemented by combining `gets` from
`Control.Monad.State.Class` with `preview` from `Control.Lens.Fold`.

```
accessElemInState :: Int -> State MyArray (Maybe Char)
accessElemInState i = gets $ preview $ ix i
```

This works just fine. However, given the plethora of functions and operators
that lens defines, I was surprised to find that there doesn't seem to be one
for this particular case.

So, my question is: Does lens define something like `gets . preview`? And if
not, what's the recommended way to implement `accessElementInState`?

---

The reason why I'm asking is because `lens` does define a special operator
outside of the state monad. While the following will not compile for the same
reason as above.

```
-- accessElemWrong :: Int -> MyArray -> Char
-- accessElemWrong i a = a ^. ix i
```

We can use the operator `(^?)` to wrap the result in a `Maybe` and perform safe
lookup.

```
accessElem :: Int -> MyArray -> Maybe Char
accessElem i a = a ^? ix i
```

Comment: I’m curious: Why does `use $ ix i` not work? What is the error message?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner The error message is that `Char` has no instance of `Monoid`. If the element type is a monoid and we try to access a missing element, then lens will instead return `mempty`. However, since `Char` has no monoid instance lens doesn't know what to do in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function [`preuse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preuse) that sounds like exactly what you're looking for:

```
accessElemInState :: Int -> State MyArray (Maybe Char)
accessElemInState i = preuse $ ix i

-- or
accessElemInState = preuse . ix
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any hints on how to find such a thing? I find the documentation of lens quite unwieldy and wouldn't know what kind of type to search for on hoogle.

Comment: @Lemming It's really hard for me to Hoogle for lens too. But if you do something like `:t gets . preview` at the repl and plug that in you can usually get results. In general though [`pre`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:pre) lets you convert functions that take lenses (like `use` or `view`) into functions that take prisms. `preview = view . pre`, `preuse = use . pre`, etc. If you learn the language -- the wordplay -- you can predict what's out there a little better. (I'm still terrible at it.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It turns out that this doesn't produce any results at `www.haskell.org/hoogle`. However, thanks to `nix` I can make my own hoogle very easily: `nix-shell -p 'haskell.packages.ghc7102.ghcWithHoogle (pkgs: with pkgs; [ lens ])'` and if I search for `Getting (First a) s a -> m (Maybe a)` in there, then it spits out `preuse` as the first result.

Comment: If you add `+lens` it seems to work on [vanilla Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Blens+Getting+%28First+a%29+s+a+-%3E+m+%28Maybe+a%29).

Comment: I did not know about that feature. Thanks!